# PUT and POST in REST API. Are they only used for semantic separation?

Tags: rest, post, put

I was asked to create an endpoint RESTfull for a fron-end team that will send me information about an user form.

There are a lot of scenarios but I will explain only 1 to try to solve my question:

1. They will send me an array that contains a lot of data about the user. For example userFirstName and userLastName. I need to check if the user exists or not in the database. If it exists, update all the data that were sent in the form. If the user do not exists, create it in the table and then create the infos related to the new user inside all related tables.

So in this scenario we can have 2 possibilities when creating a endpoint:

1. PUT  if UPDATE data
2. POST if INSERT data

I must to tell them what verb should they use when calling my endpoint, if PUT or POST.
I could give them POST and make some UPDATE during the process or I could give them a PUT and make some INSERT.

Based on RESTfull standards it should not be done. But besides this standards of best practices (to be semantic) is there any others constraints to be evaluated?

Comment: "any others constraints to be evaluated" - I don't think so. Both will do the job. You can't be pure here, it seems. So just pick one and use it. I suggest POST as more "generic".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you want to send information to the server you should use the HTTP method **POST**. In my opinion, you may create three methods, POST method to validate whether user exists and a INSERT and UPDATE method that could be called after validation.

Answer (score 0):

PUT has a very specific meaning in HTTP, which is that it signals an idempotent replacement of the representation of a resource. From [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

If you take the entity body of the PUT message, build from it a new presentation of the resource from scratch, and then replace your previous representation (think key value store), then PUT is appropriate.

On the other hand, if you are *merging* the representation provided in the body of the request with the representation you already have, then PUT is *not* appropriate.

Fielding, responding to a comment to [It is ok to use POST](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post), suggested

> we only use PUT when the update action is idempotent and the representation is complete.

In HTTP, POST is the appropriate method to use when none of the other methods are appropriate, so that's what you would use here.

But... there's no reason that you can't have more resources (more uris), including having a unique uri for each edit made to a resource.  Using PUT to create a new resource which *as a side effect* also updates some other resource is a perfectly acceptable pattern.  This new resource doesn't have to be particularly durable -- you can allow it to expire as soon as the side effect is complete.

That gives you the idempotent write semantics of PUT, without violating the complete representation constraint imposed by HTTP.